# Multi hard drives

Tags: partitioning, games, storage

I am planning on putting ubuntu on my gaming rig. Right now I have a 240 GB SSD with Windows 10 installed and a 4TB HDD for storage of my Steam library. I would like to come back from the dark side and replace Windows with Ubuntu. Dose anyone have any recommendations on a prtitopning sceem that would allow me to put ubuntu on my SSD and my games and files on my HDD

Answer (score 0):

### OS on SSD and Data on HDD

Ubuntu installed on the SSD should be able to access the games on the HDD OK. You can also put your Ubuntu "/home" partition on the HDD to save SSD space.

During the install when partitioning use "Something else". create your "/" root partition on the SSD and your "/home" partition on the HDD.

Alternatively you can install to the SSD and then create a "/home" partition on the HDD, then give the path to the new home in /etc/fstab.